# How to move date position before receiver address in scrlttr2 letter?

Tags: koma-script, scrlttr2

I can move the date position by playing around with `vspace`, like this:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \setkomavar{date}{\flushleft\vspace{-\baselineskip}\today\par
```

However, no matter which value I pick, the date still does not move above the receiver. I only care about the vertical position. How do I do this?

Comment: Please -- as usual here -- show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Answer (score 2):

If there is only the `date` in `refline`:

```latex
\documentclass[refline=dateleft]{scrlttr2}

% visualize the position of address and refline
\LoadLetterOption{visualize}
\showfields{address,refline}

\setplength{refvpos}{\useplength{toaddrvpos}}
\addtoplength[-2]{refvpos}{\baselineskip}
\addtoplength{refaftervskip}{\useplength{toaddrheight}}
\addtoplength[2]{refaftervskip}{\baselineskip}


\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Recipient}
\opening{Hello,}
some Text
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]